# How to set DateTime using mysql xdevapi in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, mysql-x-devapi

I am trying to insert a row with a DATETIME field using MySqlX.XDevAPI.
Whatever I try, I just get this cryptic message:

> Expected token type IDENT at token pos 0

I have tried string format:

> dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")

I have tried UTC seconds format:

> ((DateTimeOffset)dt).ToUnixTimeSeconds();

I have also tried just passing System.DateTime instance as a value...Nothing works, and I can't find any documentation on how to do this simple task.

What is the correct format?

Comment: You need to give us a bigger hint as to what your code actually looks like. Anything at this point would pretty much be a guessing game. [mcve]

Comment: _I am trying to insert a row with a DATETIME field using MySqlX.XDevAPI._ - It looks to me that you're somehow generating invalid MySQL SQL. Do you have an example insert statement that raises this error?

Comment: no MySqlX.XDevAP is a black box. The code is literally this: return DB.Instance.Schema.GetTable(_tableName).Insert(_data.Keys.ToArray())                .Values(_data.Values.ToArray());

Comment: if I could examine what string statement looks like I wont be asking this question. But there's no way afaik with this framework.

Comment: everything works fine if I remove this field.

Comment: the question is simple. How to set DateTime field using this framework in C#. My code is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Apparently it didn't like that the column was called "time" since it's a reserved keyword.
Now this works:
dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")